# SQL Azure Database giving "The server could not retrieve metrics (Internal Server Error)." message

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

One of my SQL Azure databases is giving me a

> The server could not retrieve metrics (Internal Server Error).

message when I click on the Metrics tab, and when I click on the Dashboard tab I get the following error:

> Failed to retrieve database information.: "Could not retrieve database information for 'YOURDATABASE'."

All other databases on that server work just fine, except that one.  Is there any way to reset the database or at least get more info on what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the question. This is a known issue in our service, is actively being addressed, and we expected a fix to be deployed soon. As a temporary workaround, please use the TSQL DMVs like sys.resource_stats to query metrics values instead of relying on this monitoring UI experience.  For more information on querying SQL Database performance DMVs, please see [Azure SQL Database Performance Guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369873.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Today - two months later - I still see the problem. Any news on when this will be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

We have fixed the key performance issues with the metrics page in Azure SQLDatabase portal and are in the process of tweaking this further. At this point portal charts should be working. If you are getting the same error as before consistently, please open a support ticket with Microsoft and we can dig into this further.

Answer (score 1):

You can login to the database directly and query sys.resource_stats dmv. There must be something wrong with the database / service, and open a support ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a short blog outlining key information components that you can get from SQL Azure... some of them, like slowest queries, are not visible in the portal even when it works, perhaps it can be of help: http://cloudmonix.com/blog/top-sql-azure-metrics-to-monitor/

Answer (score 1):

I got this same problem when I created a new database on existing server. In my case the problem was "fixed" by changing the time metrics are gathered from 24h to 1h.